# several instances of `@material-ui/styles` initialized in this application

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

We're using Material UI in our project, but there're many components that's shared between a few projects, se I'm creating a React components library to share them.

But when I import the component from library, I got the warning about `@material-ui/styles`:

```
It looks like there are several instances of `@material-ui/styles` initialized in this application.
This may cause theme propagation issues, broken class names, specificity issues, and makes your application bigger without a good reason.
```

I've checked by `npm ls @material-ui/styles` that there're only a single version.

But this problem is still happening even I added `@material-ui/core, @material-ui/styles` to the `peerDependencies`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: This is most likely a code issue, not a dependency issue.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Materal UI docs](https://material-ui.com/getting-started/faq/#i-have-several-instances-of-styles-on-the-page):

### Possible reasons

There are several common reasons for this to happen:

- You have another @material-ui/styles library somewhere in your dependencies.
- You have a monorepo structure for your project (e.g, lerna, yarn workspaces) and @material-ui/styles module is a dependency in more than one package (this one is more or less the same as the previous one).
- You have several applications that are using @material-ui/styles running on the same page (e.g., several entry points in webpack are loaded on the same page).

Comment: Yes, I think it's because I have several applications that are using @material-ui/styles, which's my component library and the project that's importing the library. Because I have already checked the version, I'm sure there's only a single version of the package and I'm not using monorepo. do you have any idea about how to fix it?

Comment: @Lai32290 One thing to be careful about here. The error message says that you have multiple **instances**. It says nothing about whether or not those instances are the same version of the library. It sounds like the problem is that you have a component library which loads @material-ui/styles and your project also loads it. Instead, you need to load the styles library in only one location.

Answer (score 0):

As said by @Code-Apprentice one or more libraries are using @material-ui/styles (I bet it's react bootstrap). It doesn't really seem to be harmful but one way of fixing it is removing dependencies that use the @material-ui/styles.